# How can I find the missing integer in a string of random non-repeating integers in a range

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I'm having trouble even beginning to think of how to do this.

I need to find a missing number in a string of random numbers that don't have separators.

Here's an example: `14036587109`. In this example, the missing number is `2`, the range is `0-10` (inclusive).

How can I write a JavaScript/Node.JS program to solve this?

The part I can't figure out is how the program separates the numbers; In the example above, how would the program know that the number `10` (before the last number) isn't the numbers `1` and `0`.

Comment: It wouldn't. With no separators or anything to distinguish between numbers, `10` might as well be (in the program's eyes) `1` and `0`

Comment: @AttoAllas So it's 100% impossible?

Comment: @AttoAllas I wouldn’t be so quick to say it’s impossible.

Comment: Well, think about it this way, if you were given the number `527106367341037` and you were told to find where the `10` was and where the `1` and the `0` were, how would you do it?

Comment: @AttoAllas It would be impossible to tell, but I'd still be able to find the missing number.

Comment: @AttoAllas: That input isn’t well-formed according to the problem (a range of consecutive integers with one missing). If it were, it wouldn’t matter which one was 10 and which one was 1, 0 – none of the three would be missing.

Comment: If you knew for sure there was only one number missing, and there was only one instance of "10", you'd know that is a 1 and a 0, and the 10 is missing.

Comment: @EliRichardson: What’s the context here? Do you need to do it efficiently, prove that it’s possible with an implementation, or…?

Comment: @Ryan The more efficient is better, but I'll settle for anything. I mainly just want to know how this would be done.

Comment: @Ryan I would definitely not say it was impossible, but there seems to be no systematic way of getting the program to deduce what the numbers are, and especially when it reaches big ranges, it might take very long, each time checking "what if this is the `1` and `0`" and "what if this is the `10`", "what if instead it's a `104`?". My comment was just pointing out that there is no way for the program to differentiate, not that it was impossible

Comment: @EliRichardson: One immediate silly option: try every possible division. There are 2^(n − 1), and each one takes at most n log n time to try, for a complexity of O(n 2^n log n). There’s definitely an efficient way, but this way satisfies “anything” =) (Also that’s not the tightest bound for the approach, just an upper bound.)

Comment: May I ask where this question is from? Google interview, competitive programming thing, or…?

Comment: @Ryan Saw a codegolf about it a few days ago. Made me really curious as to how it would be done.

Comment: A slightly more efficient way would be to try interpreting the start as `1`, checking if the rest of the string matches, try again with `14` if it doesn’t, etc. I think that has complexity O(2^n). Then there’s the option of trying every possible starting point (minimums of each length), for a time I don’t feel up to analyzing right now but might be as good as O(n²)?

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean? Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: @EliRichardson: Which one?

Comment: @Ryan The first one.

Comment: Posting as a comment because it's not a full solution: You don't need to split the input string into numbers. Create an array of 10 integers containing the number of occurrences of each digit that should be in the string. Iterate from across the range from start to end and count how many of each digit you should have. Then iterate over the input string one digit at a time and count how many of each digit you actually have. The discrepancy should tell you which digits are missing, and the missing number must be composed of these digits. Then the question becomes which ordering is correct.

Comment: This reminds me of the problem from Jon Bentley's Programming Pearls

Comment: @samgak: I don’t think the start and end are known, but counting digits is probably part of the right approach.

Comment: @samgak If all the permutations of the missing digits are present in the input, you may still have to unravel the whole thing to get the answer. But it is indeed a good starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things we know about the missing integer: the total number of digits in the input tells us the number of digits in the missing integer, and (as @samgak mentioned in a comment) counting the occurrences of each digit in the input tells us which digits the missing integer is made of. This may give us a quick path to the solution, if one of the permutations of those digits is missing from the input. If it doesn't, then:

Find the integers from highest to lowest number of digits; if the range is e.g. 0-999, then search the 3-digit integers first, then 2, then 1.

If an integer is only present at one location in the input, mark it as found, and remove it from the input.

Then, start again with the longest integers that haven't been found yet, and look at the ones that are present at two locations; try both options, and then check whether all other integers that rely on the digits we're using are also present; e.g. if 357 is present at two locations:

```
... 1235789 ... 2435768 ...
      357         357
     23          43
    123         243
     235         435
       578         576
        78          76
        789         768
```

When trying the first location for the 357, check whether there is another possibility for 23, 123, 235, 578, 78, and 789. For the second location, check 43, 243, 435, 576, 76 and 768.

If these checks show that only one of the options is possible, mark the number as found and remove it from the input.

Go on to do this for shorter integers, and for integers that are present at 3, 4, ... locations. If, after doing this to a certain point, there is still no result, you may have to recursively try several options, which will quickly lead to a huge number of options. (With especially crafted large input, it is probably possible to thwart this method and make it unusably slow.) But the average complexity with random input may be decent.

---

Actually, when you find an integer that is only present in one location in the input, but it is a permutation of the missing digits, you should not remove it, because it could be the missing integer. So the algorithm might be: remove all integers you can unequivocally locate in the input, then try removing all possible missing integers one by one, and look for inconsistencies, i.e. other missing numbers that don't have the correct length or digits.

---

It's all a question of heuristics, of course. You try something simple, if that doesn't work you try something more complicated, if that doesn't work, you try something even more complicated... and at each step there are several options, and each one could be optimal for some input strings but not for others.

E.g. if the range is 0-5000, you'd start by marking the 4-digit integers that are only present at one location. But after that, you could do the same thing again (because integers that were present twice could have had one of their options removed) until there's no more improvement, or you could check integers that are present twice, or integers that are present up to x times, or move on to 3-digit integers... I don't think there's a straightforward way to know which of these options will give the best result.

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work for any input string and any start/end range:

We can think about the numbers in the string as a pool of digits that we can choose from. We start at `startRange` and go through to `endRange`, looking for each number along the way in our pool of digits.

When we find a number that can be composed from our pool of digits, we delete those digits from our pool of digits, as those digits are already being used to form a number in our range.

As soon as we come across a number that cannot be composed from our pool of digits, that must be the missing number.

```js
const str = "14036587109"; // input

const numsLeft = str.split("").map(num => parseInt(num)); // array of numbers

const startRange = 0;
const endRange = 10;

for(let i = startRange; i <= endRange ; i++) {
    
    // check if number can be formed given the numbers left in numsLeft
    const numFound = findNum(numsLeft, i);

    if(!numFound) {
        console.log("MISSING: " + i); // prints 2 
        break;
    }
}

function findNum(numsLeft, i) {
    
    // array of digits
    const numsToFind = String(i).split("").map(num => parseInt(num)); 
    
    // default is true, if all digits are found in numsLeft
    let found = true; 

    numsToFind.forEach(num => {

        // find digit in numsLeft
        const numFoundIndex = numsLeft.indexOf(num); 

        if(numFoundIndex < 0) { 

            // digit was not found in numsLeft
            found = false;
            return;

        } else {

            // digit was found; delete digit from numsLeft
            numsLeft.splice(numFoundIndex, 1); 
        }

    });

    return found;
}
```

Comment: We're looking for integers, not digits. If the input contains 123, 124 and 125, which one are you going to use for 12? Because that could be the only 23, 24 or 25 in the input.

Comment: I see how my wording was confusing -- modified answer to better articulate the algorithm.

Comment: This doesn't always seem to work. This number, for example: `2073211275131529188172624251291923163022210284116` returns 21, when it should return 14. (Range 1-30)

Comment: I have just tested your code with a very large range (1000 separate numbers), removed the *specific* 59 (the correct one) and it outputted 995 (after of course having changed `endRange`). The number is [here](https://pastebin.com/TFUaEJjG) if you want to try for yourself. I am not sure if this is a flaw with your code or the question, but it does not output the correct number.

Comment: A simple example: "111101223456789" (0-12) is missing 0, but returns 10 (because it doesn't notice its solution has two 1's).

Comment: @EliRichardson should it return 14? Going by the algorithm, we are deleting each number from 1-30, and by the time we reach 14, we've deleted five 1s and one 4 (`1, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13`), and we still have several 1s and one 4 left in the string, so 14 is still composable by the digits left in the string

Comment: Ohh, nevermind. I see what you're saying -- my analogy of a pool of digits is flawed as "10" can't be thought about as "1" and "0" for any number to use.

Comment: The algorithm needs slight modification to work: findNum should tell you if the digits are found *consecutively* in the array, not if they are found in any place in the array. I'll work on that edit.

Answer (score -1):

```
var input = '10436587109';
var range = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0];
var expr1 = new RegExp(range.join('|'),'g');
var expr2 = new RegExp('[0-9]','g');

var a = input.match(expr1).map(Number).concat(input.match(expr2).map(Number));
var x = range.filter(function(i){ return a.indexOf(i)===-1; });
```

Comment: This gives the wrong answer for the input `'10436587109'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this code doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Ryan check new version please

Comment: Now gives the wrong answer for `'02345678910'` (should be `1`)